# Monitor-Specific Color Profile Results In Yellow Grayscale Images

Tags: windows-7, lcd, color-profiles, windows-live-photo

I recently purchased a new Acer S201hl monitor. Many lay reviews compliment its color accuracy with people noting only a bit of a blueish tinge.

After a little time, Windows found, and I installed, the Acer drivers via Microsoft Update. During the installation process, the software installed an ICC profile for the monitor from Acer.

I recently noticed that when I view photos using Windows Live Photo Gallery, the colors are wrong. For example, grayscale document scans appear with yellow backgrounds instead of white backgrounds. This happens with both my external monitors and my ThinkPad's built-in screen. When I removed the monitor-specific profile from the list of profiles associated with a monitor (for example, removing the Acer profile from the Acer monitor), the problem went away for that screen.

I checked with Microsoft KB939395 and though it says "an incorrect color profile [...] is used for the monitor," the profile associated with my ThinkPad's screen seemed to be correct, based on its name.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the KB article is too nice to monitor companies.

http://www.mydigitallife.info/windows-vista-photo-gallery-yellow-tint-background-problem/ goes into greater detail and says that certain brands, such as Samsung, tend to ship broken ICC profiles. The broken ICC profile then causes problems.

The fix is the same as the one outlined in the KB. One merely goes back to using the default Windows ICC.

At least 1 person reports that this bug also affects Photoshop, which is understandable because Photoshop also uses ICC profiles.

Since it's possible to generate a new ICC profile and use it thanks to the Windows Color Calibrator, it's possible to have a working custom ICC profile. I haven't tried using the calibrator to twiddle with the color values though.

Just Guessing:

It is possible but unlikely that both Photoshop and Windows Live have a bug.

It is possible and somewhat likely that something about how Windows handles ICC profiles is causing the hiccup.